# Why does Lamech speak of himself using the third person? (Genesis 4:23-24)

Tags: genesis, linguistics

Genesis 4:23-24 NKJV

> 23 Then Lamech said to his wives:
>
> “Adah and Zillah, hear my voice; **Wives of Lamech**, listen to my speech!
> For I have killed a man for wounding me, Even a young man for hurting
> me. 24 If Cain shall be avenged sevenfold, Then Lamech
> seventy-sevenfold.”

Why does Lamech speak of himself using the third person?

Comment: It was Hebrew idiom for prophecy.  Jesus did the same thing.